# Is it possible to change the productId of the appstore products in xCode settings?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription, swiftystorekit

I am facing one issue regarding in-app purchase.I tried searching out lot but ended up here for the help. My client had asked me to change the bundleId of the ios and change the account for releasing the app. Thus I had to create a new app in appStoreConnect for implementing in-app purchase prices.
The issue is I have done all the necessary steps related to in-app purchase, but still not getting product details in my code.
I am using SwiftyStoreKit for the same.
I don't know where I am going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Product Ids which you already set in App Store are set for good. They cannot be changed or reused across other apps you have (even if you delete one product with a specific Id, you cannot create a new product with the same Id).
You can check the Revenue Cat docs, they explain how apple products work pretty well https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/ios-products